# IOS Universal App Rotation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, orientation

I have recently converted my IPad application into a Universal Application. I am re-using a lot of views from my IPad version to the IPhone version.

The IPad needs to support all orientations, is there a way to specify the IPad version to allow any orientation, but IPhone to just allow portrait?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you might guess, there are some alternative ways to get the same result. The following would let you define multiple orientations for each device.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```